# understanding Jquery code to highlight navbar item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am new to Jquery and wanted to understand better .

i was using bootstrap scroll-spy to change my navigation highlight as i keep scrolling the page or when i click the particular link , now that default plugin in bootstrap is't very customizable , so i searched stackoverflow and found a great peace of code that works perfect . though the current requirements are such that i will have to further modify this code to suit my needs . but i am unable to understand the complete code given by the developer .

the original JSfiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

below is the code .

```
enter code here  $(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
       menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#menu-center a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

Now i went through this code and i saw that quite a few Jquery functions were used such as on() and off() and location.hash . so i went and checked the Jquery documentation and learned the functions i was't familiar with , most of it made sense , but some parts still did't .

```
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
```

i have no clue whats happening in the above peice of code . i understand the usage of the stop() function . after the 'swing' bit why the function ?? what is that really doing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter in the animate method is a callback; once the animation is complete, that anonymous function is invoked.

The first line of the anonymous function

```
window.location.hash = target;
```

changes the hash part of the url, e.g the part after the '#'. This preserves back button functionality.

As for the second line

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
```

notice about a dozen lines above where it says:

```
$(document).off("scroll");
```

The scroll event is turned off before animate is called. So, the second line in the anonymous function turns it back on.

Comment: Yes callback function Exactly , thats what i wanted to know . Thanks . i do understood the on and off bit and also notice that onclick() the event handler gets turned off and when the callback function gets called the event handler is attached again .

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` adds an eventHandler (less common but part of the standard) and 
`.off()` removes it

`window.location.hash` changes the part after the hash:
`window.location.hash = "example";` produces "www.blah.com/**#example**"

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
}, 500, 'swing', function () {
```

Here 500 is the duration of the animation, 'swing' is the type of animation and the function is the callback that will be called when the animation is complete

Comment: i totally understood this , even before i posted the question , thanks for ur reply  , please read my question again and see the part i don't understand , that i have pointed out . Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit . one last thing why the +2 , is that just kindda fancy math ?